# How to insert PHP variable into section of javascript, using DOMDocument?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using DomDocument to modify a HTML file that is resaved in a new folder.

There are a few PHP variables I am adding into the HTML elements, but I need to be able to add some variables into a section of javascript.

How can I achieve this?

Alternatively, is there any other way to take a HTML file and insert PHP variables into it and save the result? Maybe a super basic and lightweight template engine? (Must be able to read the HTML into memory)

Example HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
        var my_array = new Array();
        </script>
    <body>
</html>
```

Example PHP:

```
$doc->DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html_from_file);

// somehow need to target my_array;

$doc->saveHTMLFile($filename);
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the JavaScript?

Comment: See edit for example

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if I understand very well your question but in principle you could access the script tag in the DOM as any other tag with, for example:

```
$script = $doc->getElementsByTagName('script')->item(0) // if you want the first match
```

Now you can retrieve and modify, if needed, its content with the nodeValue property.

Comment: It will contain quite a lot of code, how easy is it to add in the variable in a specific place? Thinking about it, I may write the variable to a javascript file and just reference that in the html?

Comment: The content of the script node is just text so you will have to get via de nodeValue property and parse it via regular expressions or the like and later put it back again in place. There is no DOM tool that will allow you to that. At least not  to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a script tag with PHP, like this:

```
echo "<script>var blah = $blah;</script>";
```

Comment: I already have a script tag inside the HTML, that contains an array I need to add my PHP variable to (the PHP variable contains a string)

Comment: You can insert PHP variables into the JavaScript in the same way you do with HTML

Comment: Then just add PHP code to that part of the HTML. You can pretty much put PHP anywhere in your page.

Comment: @TroyThompson but with HTML, you have to find the DOM element, e.g. an anchor tag, or a div with a certain class. How do I target a specific javascript variable? What's the DOMDocument method for that?